# What is the name of (1 - sum of component-wise min)? Is it a metric?

Tags: metric-spaces, terminology

I want to compare text in order to identify the language of the text. One way to do so is to count the frequency of a fixed set of characters for the text of unknown language and compare it with the character frequencies of the candidate languages.

Let $x, y \in [0, 1]^n$ with the property (p1) $\sum_{i=1}^n x^{(i)} = 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n y^{(i)} = 1$. Let $d: [0,1]^n \times [0,1]^n \rightarrow [0, 1]$ be
$$d(x, y) := 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n \min(x^{(i)}, y^{(i)})$$

**Does $d$ have a name?**

### Is d a metric?

1. Non-negativity: Due to (p1)
2. $d(x,y) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = y$

   1. $d(x,y) = 0 \Rightarrow x = y$: Due to (p1), $d(x, y) = 0$ means that $x$ and $y$ have to be component-wise identical if $d(x, y) = 0$.
   2. $x = y \Rightarrow d(x,y) = 0$: If $x = y$, then $d(x, y) := 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n \min(x^{(i)}, y^{(i)}) = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n x^{(i)} = 1-1 = 0$
3. Symmetry: $\min$ is symmetrical
4. Triangle inequality: $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y, z)$

This is where I'm not too sure:

\begin{align}
d(x,y) + d(y, z) &= (1 - \sum_{i=1}^n \min(x^{(i)}, y^{(i)})) + (1 - \sum_{i=1}^n \min(y^{(i)}, z^{(i)}))\\
  &= 2 - (\sum_{i=1}^n \min(x^{(i)}, y^{(i)}) + \sum_{i=1}^n \min(y^{(i)}, z^{(i)}))\\
  &= 2 - \sum_{i=1}^n (\min(x^{(i)}, y^{(i)}) + \min(y^{(i)}, z^{(i)}))\\
  &\stackrel{?}{\ge} 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n \min(x^{(i)}, z^{(i)})\\
\end{align}

### Why I'm confident that d is a metric

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Try to find counter-examples to the hypothesis that d is a metric."""

import numpy
numpy.random.seed(28041990)


def d(x, y):
    """The metric candidate."""
    assert len(x) == len(y)
    return 1 - sum(min(xi, yi) for xi, yi in zip(x, y))


def test(num_tries, dim):
    for _ in range(num_tries):
        x = numpy.random.random((dim, ))
        y = numpy.random.random((dim, ))
        z = numpy.random.random((dim, ))
        # normalize
        x = x / sum(x)
        y = y / sum(y)
        z = z / sum(z)
        epsilon = 0.0001  # not (d(x, z) <= d(x, y) + d(y, z))
        if not (d(x, z) <= d(x, y) + d(y, z) + epsilon):
            print("Counter-Example: x={} y={} z={}".format(x, y, z))
            print("d(x, z) = {} > {} = {} + {} = d(x,y) + d(y,z)"
                  .format(d(x, z), d(x, y) + d(y, z), d(x, y), d(y, z)))
            return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test(num_tries=10**7, dim=4)  # tried with dim=3, dim=4 and dim=5
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a name for this, but $d$ certainly is a metric. To conclude your proof of the triangle inequality, observe that subtracting a minimum becomes a maximum
$$-\min(a,b) = \max(-a,-b)$$
and apply the estimate 
$$\max(a,c) \leq a+c\leq \max(a,b)+\max(b,c).$$